# Помогите понять формулу из книги Д. Кнута

Tags: алгоритм

Мне нужно протестировать ЛКГ с помощью критерия сериальной корреляции из Д. Кнута (2 том, 95 стр). И чтобы лучше понять я решила сделать упражнение 18(б), но у меня никак не получается правильный числитель можете помочь где ошибка? (подстановка для n =3)
[image: Сама формула для критерия сериальной корреляции]

Вот мое решение:
[image: мое решение]

Правильный ответ:
[image: Правильный ответ]

Как я понимаю, что моя ошибка это 2 перед U_0 U_1, но я не понимаю как тогда без нее?

Comment: Несколько раз проверил сам. Потом ввел его [cюда](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=3%5C%2840%29u_0u_1%2Bu_1u_0%2Bu_1u_2%2Bu_2u_0%5C%2841%29-Power%5B%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29u_0%2Bu_1%5C%2841%29%2B%5C%2840%29u_2%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D) - у вас все правильно. Или вы не так условие переписали)

Comment: @РусланМамедов не условие правильное, но ответ другой хы(